# Stationarity and trends in ARIMA models

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, trend

For this question I am interested in rigorous proofs or in references explaining details.

Let us suppose we have an ARIMA process of order $(p,d,q)=(p,0,q)$:

$$A(L)X_t=B(L)\epsilon_t [1],$$

where $A$ and $B$ are polynomials in the lag operator $L$ of order $p$ and $q$ respectively. $\epsilon_t$ are i.i.d. normal variables of variance $\sigma$ and zero mean.

1. Would it be possible for the same choice of the parameters, i.e. A, B and $\sigma$, to have two different stationary distributions ?

To clarify the question, we can define stationary distribution for this question this way. Equation [1] can be considered a way to propagate the time series given some initial conditions. If propagating according to [1] we converge to a constant probability distribution than we call this a stationary distribution. In Markov chains we have a similar setting for example, but the stationary distribution can be not unique (unless some assumptions are verified), and dependent on the initial conditions. There are ARMA process withouth stationary distribution (for example in the presence of a unit root). My question is if there are ARMA process having more than one stationary distributions.

2. Would it be possible to have a limit cyclostationary distribution ?See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclostationary_process for definition.

For "limit cyclostationary distribution" I mean an ARMA process that, given some initial configuration, will behave in a long run as a (wide-sense) cyclostationary process, with a mean and variance changing cyclically over time.

3. Now let's take $d \ge 1$, so that the differentiated process $Y_t=(1-L)^d X_t$ is an $ARIMA(p,0,q)$ process. Suppose now that the $ARMA(p,q)$ process $Y_t$ has a stationary distribution. Is it true that $X_t$ will be of the form $X_t=f_t +Y_t$ where $Y_t$ is stationary and $f_t$ is deterministic and respects $(1-L)^d f_t=0$ (so that the trend must be linear, quadratic, cubic as $d$ increases)?

Comment: The common parameterization is AR, I, MA: $(p,d,q)$, not $(p,q,d)$. Introducing a different, nonstandard ordering of parameters invites potential confusion. AR$(p,q,0)$ and AR$(p,q)$ do not seem to make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping improve the question. I hope I edited it with a consistent notation. Do not hesitate to suggest other improvements.

Comment: Please motivate -1 . Bad habit of putting -1 without explanation... This habit damages stackexchange sites.

Comment: What a nice person would do is : (1) explain why the question is not well posed (considering that any question is a good question, if well posed) ; (2) wait for changes by the OP ; (3) If these changes are not performed, put a -1 . Everything else in my opinion is just unpolite .

Comment: Agreed. But maybe put a -1 for a bad question and retract the vote once the question is improved? After all, it is only logical to vote on the question as is, not as it was or will/might be. (I did not downvote.)

Comment: This is of course reasonable, provided that it comes with an explanation/suggestion for improvement in the comments below the question. Anyway, following what you say, when I have a bit of time I will modify my question and clarify some points that came up as unclear/undefined in an answer below. For the moment, I thank you for the discussion.

Comment: I tried to improve the question. I would expect than to see either further comments or a removal of the -1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Question does not quite make sense. Stationary distributions are not identified by ARMA parameters of the series. For the same ARMA parameter $A$ and $B$ (with stationary solution), any i.i.d. $\epsilon_t$ with finite second moment would give a strictly stationary series. Different marginal distribution of $\epsilon_t$ would give different stationary distribution. For a trivial example, take i.i.d. white noise with different distributions.
2. What is "limit cyclostationary distribution"...? An example of cyclostationary *series* is seasonal ARIMA time series---e.g. the seasonal AR(1) specification
   $$
   (1- \phi L^{12}) X_t = \epsilon_t.
   $$
   In SARIMA notation, this is an SARIMA(0,0,0)$\times$(1,0,0)$_{12}$ model. Its ACF is 
   $\rho(12h) = \phi^h$, and zero at other lags.
3. No, clearly this is not true---e.g. take the unit root $(1-L) X_t = \epsilon_t$. In fact, given the way you've specified ARMA series (with not intercept), there can be no deterministic trend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here some points. (1) I am considering $\epsilon_i$ 
normal i.i.d. variables with a variance $\sigma$. My question is if such a ARMA model can have different 
stationary distributions at fixed A, B and $\sigma$ . I think no but I just wanted to be sure if there is a proof of this.

Comment: (2) The model you write is $X_t=\phi X_{t-12}+\epsilon_t$ with no intercept. So essentially there are 12 indipendent AR(1) processes. 
Each process has than zero mean, which is a bit of a trivial case of a cyclostationary signal, where the expectation value $E[X(t)]$ 
can be non-constant and oscillate (see the wikipedia page). Can such cyclostationary signals be modelled via an ARMA process ?

Comment: (3) I am not getting your answer. If we have $A(L)X_t=B(L) \epsilon_t$ and $Y_t=X_t-k_1$ with $k_1$ constant, than $A(L)Y_t=A(L)X_t-k_2$ where the constant $k_2$ is $k_1$ times the number of non-zero terms of $A$. This shows that the intercept term causes a constant mean shift but not a trend. Further an ARIMA model with $d \ge 1$ has been defined exactly so that deterministic trends can be removed by the differentiation operation, or am I wrong? Therefore such models can contain deterministic trends.

Comment: 1) With i.i.d. normal error term, then question is trivial---Gaussian time series are characterized by the autocovariance function.

Comment: 2) Covariance-stationarity implies mean stationary. In particular, ARMA processes are mean-stationary---one can always demeaning, a general wide-sense cyclostationary process. ("Cyclostationarity" is not really time series vernacular.)

Comment: 3) If you include intercept term in the I(0) ARMA process, then sure, the I(1) process obtained by integrating can have deterministic trend. But answer to question is still no---an I(I) process is not a sum of deterministic trend plus a stationary process.Again, consider the simple unit root process. Take 0 to be the trivial "deterministic trend". Where is your stationary component Y?

Comment: Thanks again. Here my relpy. (1) To complete this answer I think one would need to show that: (1) if a stationary distrubution exists for an ARMA process, than it is 
Gaussian. (2) that the autocovariance function is univocally identified from the ARMA parameters.

Comment: (2) I sent the link to the 
wikipedia page for the definition of cyclostationarity, where it says that 
in such a signal the covariance function also is cyclic in t. I think the answer to my question is there when you say ARMA process are always mean stationary. How one can show this ? If you have a unit root they are not mean stationary but it may be a limit example.

Comment: (3) The process you show is a good one. Xt=Xt−1+ϵt (σ2=1) is the discrete analogue of the Brownian motion. We can fix X(0)=0 and see: - Xt∼N(0,t),t>1 ; - Yt=Xt−Xt−1=ϵt and Xt−Yt=Xt−1 is non deterministic. But here I would not say that Xt has a trend, because the mean does not change over time, even if there is not a stationary distribution. But you are right to say that this phenomenon makes my claim false, as it is written.

Comment: ( as a side, referring to your original answer to point 3, the fact that there cannot be deterministic trends without intercept (after differentiating) I think is not right. Take an ARIMA(p,d=2,q) process without intercept and add $+\alpha t$ manually as a trend. Differentiating twice the new process leads to an ARMA(p,q) process without intercept. Maybe what you had in mind is that if one integrates an ARMA(p,q) without intercept one cannot build a process with deterministic trends (even if, as your example shows, one may get a non-stationary process ) )

Comment: ( I also notice that I did not answer to what I mean as "limit cyclostationary distribution", for question 2. I mean an ARMA process that has a "cyclostationary process" as a steady state. Does this make more sense ? You are right to say that this definition is not very common: it is of course a bit different than having a stationary distribution. The general idea of the question is if an ARMA process can model cyclostationary signals, as defined in wikipedia. I hope this makes the question clearer. )

Comment: Please have a look at the modified question that I tried to modify to make it clearer.